# Cannot find module 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular/side-drawer-directives'

Tags: telerik, angular

Now that Nativescript UI can be used with Angular 2, I'm trying to put the sidedrawer. The problem is not about the code itself (it's very clear) but there is this line in this [file](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started/getting-started.component.ts) (this line can be found in other files too well at least the from part):

```
import {RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType, MainTemplateDirective, DrawerTemplateDirective} from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular/side-drawer-directives";
```

So when I put this line, the Typescript compiler tells me it cannot find the module. Am I missing anything ?

Thank you in advance

Edit : I'm not sure but doesn't the problem come from the fact that the definition type file (*.d.ts) is missing ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now identified by Telerik's dev team and will be solved in the next Nativescript UI release as it is mentioned on the Github issue : https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/issues/1#issuecomment-219940175